# Where can I report spam on Stackoverflow?

Tags: support, spam

Actually, I know how to flag it, but I apparently don't have the reputation necessary to do so. I also don't have the reputation needed to chat…so I'm posting this here:

Last comment here is spam:
[Replace "add new comment" link with image in Drupal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2670117/drupal-add-new-comment-link-to-image)

Answer (score 4):

If it's bothering you, and you do not have the reputation to flag, and it's older than 10 minutes then email using the "contact us" link in the footer.

In general, spam answers do not last longer than a minute or so on Stack Overflow.